# Is "git clone -b name url" versus "git clone url --branch name" are the same?

Tags: git, git-branch

I would like to know if these two `git` commands are the exact same?

```
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky --branch daisy

git clone -b daisy git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky.git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to git manual page theese commands are equal:

```
$ git help clone
 ....
 --branch <name>, -b <name>
 Instead of pointing the newly created HEAD to the branch pointed to by the cloned repository’s HEAD, point to <name> branch instead. In a non-bare
 repository, this is the branch that will be checked out.  --branch can also take tags and detaches the HEAD at that commit in the resulting
repository.
 ....
```

As you could see `-b` and `--branch` are just synonyms. Missing extension `.git` (in the first case) is determined automatically (taking into account the protocol `git://`) and order of parameters does not matter.